# Problems deserializing binary created with .NET Framework in .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, deserialization

Good day,

I tried to port a .NET Framework console app to .NET Core 3.0. But when I start the Core version I get an exception at the point where a binary file is deserialized.

This binary file was created with object serialization in another .NET Framework program using the BinaryFormatter class.

To deserialize it I am referencing the DLL containing the serialized class.
So the code snipped from the console app is:

```
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        EthCatalog = (EthernetCatalog)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

Where EthernetCatalog comes form the referenced DLL.
And the exception I get is:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Type 'System.Net.IPAddress' in Assembly 'System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.'

so apparently somewhere in the EthernetCatalog class IPAddress class is used. This class is serializable in .NET Framework but not in .NET Core.

**So my first question is can you make this work? Can I deserialize the file containing the EthernetCatalog object in .NET Core although the EthernetCatalog class is defined in a .NET Framework DLL? Like tell the Deserilized just to set everything to null that cannot be deserialized?**

When investigating the problem I got actually more confused and more questions came up:

1. Why is the .NET Framework DLL containing the EthernetCatalog class even using the IPAddress class from .NET Core?

   I would have expected when referencing .NET Framework DLLs in .NET Core that the .NET Framework DLLs are still using … well, the .NET Framework versions of all .NET classes.
2. Is the attribute [System.Serializable] not used anymore in .NET Core?

   When I look at the MS .net documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization there is a list of classes that can be used with BinaryFormatter. And every class in this list did not use the attribute [System.Serializable] when looking at the .NET Core documentation. But the attribute [System.Serializable] IS used for all these classes (that I checked) when switching to the .NET Framework documentation.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: A class object has bookkeeping values that get serialized a long with the data.  Deserialize only works when the data and booking values are the same as when serialized.  I know you have to recompile when you change Net Versions  of serialization to work.  So make sure you do a clean build to make sure all intermediate object files are recompiled with the Core version you are using.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Why is the .NET Framework DLL containing the EthernetCatalog class even using the IPAddress class from .NET Core?

It doesn't. .NET has a type forwarding feature that makes possible to resolve types with their legacy .NET Framework identity. Feel free to check the .NET Core assemblies (the path is something like `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.0.0`), you will find the `System.dll` even in .NET Core (where `IPAddress` resided in .NET Framework). But try to disassembly it and you will see that it does not contain any types but a bunch of assembly attributes. Among others:

```
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(IPAddress))]
```

where `IPAddress` references the new place of the type in the `System.Net.Primitives` assembly. That's why you get the error message for the new identity.

> 2. Is the attribute [System.Serializable] not used anymore in .NET Core?

It is, but many class that were serializable in .NET Framework are not serializable anymore in .NET Core (delegates, types, reflection members, streams, encoding, culture info, etc.). Ironically enough, the type forwarding mechanism is to support serialization, specifically `BinaryFormatter` mechanisms but it seems there are some types, which are not serializable anymore and they are still forwarded.

**Possible solutions:**

As a rule of thumb if you need to serialize objects across platforms you should prefer some text-based serialization such as XML or JSON.

But even if you really need to deserialize a legacy stream with `BinaryFormatter` there are some possible workarounds.

1. Set the `SurrogateSelector` property of the `BinaryFormatter` to customize the deserialization of some types. Maybe the easiest solution if you use my [CustomSerializerSurrogateSelector](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/?topic=html/T_KGySoft_Serialization_Binary_CustomSerializerSurrogateSelector.htm), which is exactly for this purpose. From its documentation:

```cs
// deserializing a MemoryStream in .NET Core that was serialized in .NET Framework
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter { SurrogateSelector = new CustomSerializerSurrogateSelector() };
var memoryStream = (MemoryStream)formatter.Deserialize(streamSerializedInNetFramework);
```

As you see I used it for `MemoryStream` but it should work the same way for `IPAddress` as well. You can download the library from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/)

2. Another solution is to use a `SerializationBinder` that has to be assigned to the `Binder` property of the binary formatter: Redirect the `IPAddress` to a custom serializable class, which should implement `IObjectReference`. You have to implement the `GetRealObject` method, which must return a proper `IPAddress` instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't yet tried your suggested solutions but just to comment one point in you answer: You say the  [System.Serializable] is still used in .net core. But if you look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization it is stated you can e.g. use the Array class with BinaryFormatter in.NET Core but if you click on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netcore-3.1 you see no [System.Serializable] while it is still here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The generated documentation is not perfect. But `Array` [is still serializable](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Array.cs,18) in .NET Core (but it depends also on the element type, of course).

Comment: Hallo György Kőszeg, I tried your nuget package and the SurrogateSelector = new CustomSerializerSurrogateSelector() option but now I get the exception System.ArgumentException: 'Type 'System.UInt64' is not deserializable.'
 in the same code line. And yes according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization Int64 is serializable with .net core while UInt64 is not. This seems very wired to me. I think I will abandon my porting efford here and stay with with the .net Framework version.

Comment: That is weird indeed. UInt64 should be natively supported even by the plain old `BinaryFormatter`. If you can upload the stream somewhere (along with the dll containing this `EthernetCatalog`) maybe I could investigate the problem.

Comment: I also tried to put the deserialization into a separate project .net Framework project into my new .net Core solution but I get exactly the same exceptions so this does not work either.

Comment: Just to correct the my own comment from earlier today: The sentence "And yes according to learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/… Int64 is serializable with .net core while UInt64 is not." is wrong. Both Int64 and Uint64 are serializable in .net core according to the MS documentation

Comment: After moving to .NET Standard, I was getting the `SerializationException` when using `System.CodeDom.CodeNamespace` with `BinaryFormatter`. This answer solved the issue for me.